# Trouble removing package using Yum on CentOS7

Tags: centos7, yum, rpm

**Problem:** Removing python-boto from the system and Yum. It appears to be no longer installed, but still appears in Yum.

**Tried:** yum clean all; yum check; rpm -e --noscripts python-boto and rpm -e --noscripts python-boto.noarch but has not resolved. Use find to check if package appears to be there. See below for detailed results of each.

**Question:** What else can I try and what risks are there with trying it

```
# yum list | grep boto
python-boto.noarch                      2.25.0-2.el7.centos             extras
python-boto3.noarch                     1.4.6-5.el7                     base
python2-XStatic-roboto-fontface.noarch  0.4.3.2-4.el7                   epel
python2-boto.noarch                     2.45.0-3.el7                    epel
python2-boto3.noarch                    1.4.6-1.el7                     epel
python2-botocore.noarch                 1.6.0-1.el7                     epel


# yum remove python-boto
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No Match for argument: python-boto
No Packages marked for removal


# yum clean all --verbose
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "product-id" plugin
Loading "search-disabled-repos" plugin
Loading "subscription-manager" plugin
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Config time: 0.074
Yum version: 3.4.3
Cleaning repos: base epel extras mariadb nodesource openproject-ce remi
              : remi-php56 remi-php73 remi-safe updates
Operating on /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7 (see CLEAN OPTIONS in yum(8) for details)
Disk usage of /var/cache/yum/*/* after cleanup:
0      enabled repos
16 M   disabled repos:
  16 M   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/centosplus
0      untracked repos
628    other data:
  628    /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
16 M   total


# yum list | grep boto
python-boto.noarch                      2.25.0-2.el7.centos             extras
python-boto3.noarch                     1.4.6-5.el7                     base
python2-XStatic-roboto-fontface.noarch  0.4.3.2-4.el7                   epel
python2-boto.noarch                     2.45.0-3.el7                    epel
python2-boto3.noarch                    1.4.6-1.el7                     epel
python2-botocore.noarch                 1.6.0-1.el7                     epel


# yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
check all


# yum list | grep boto
python-boto.noarch                      2.25.0-2.el7.centos             extras
python-boto3.noarch                     1.4.6-5.el7                     base
python2-XStatic-roboto-fontface.noarch  0.4.3.2-4.el7                   epel
python2-boto.noarch                     2.45.0-3.el7                    epel
python2-boto3.noarch                    1.4.6-1.el7                     epel
python2-botocore.noarch                 1.6.0-1.el7                     epel


# yum remove python-boto
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No Match for argument: python-boto
No Packages marked for removal


# find / -name *boto* -print
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore-1.12.134.dist-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3-1.9.134.dist-info

# rpm -e python-boto
error: package python-boto is not installed
# rpm -e --noscrips python-boto
rpm: --noscrips: unknown option
# rpm -e --noscripts python-boto
error: package python-boto is not installed
# rpm -e --noscripts python-boto.noarch
error: package python-boto.noarch is not installed
```

Your help greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW, you have the subscription-manager yum plugin enabled. Unless you're going to attach this system to a Red Hat Satellite / Spacewalk server for updates, you can and should disable/remove it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package isn't installed at all.

`yum list` lists *all* available packages, whether installed or not.

To show only installed packages, use `yum list installed`.

```
yum list installed | grep boto
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find installed packages in rpm based distribution is **rpm -qa|grep** , so first ensure package is installed if it is installed you can remove package from either **rpm -e** or use **yum remove** . I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files are coming from another package I'd try:

`yum whatprovides /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3-1.9.134.dist-info`

to locate the package containing the file, or `rpm -qf /path/to/file`.